# SQLAlchemy query filter_by using OR

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need a way of doing smething similar to this:

```
page = request.args.get('page',1,type=int)
posts = Post.query.filter_by(area = current_user.area).order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).paginate(per_page=5)

return render_template('home.html',posts =posts)
```

However the code above didn't work because this would simply ignore everything after the word "or"

I also tried something relatively simiar to this(reference:http://www.leeladharan.com/sqlalchemy-query-with-or-and-like-common-filters)

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
filter(or_(User.name == 'leela', User.name == 'akshay'))
```

but the logic behind this is using "filter" and not "filter_by"; also the type of the above is filter class which I didn't really know how to used it to my adventages.

If anyone could help, that would be much apreciated:)

Comment: There is no `"or"` in the first example.  Can you clarify what it is you are trying to do please?  Some sample data and expected query output would help.

Comment: @snakecharmerb The question is solved now! THKS for stopping by tho <3
I solved this problem by putting a if statement in html to filter.